# Angular2: json does not exist on type object

Tags: json, angular

I am beginner. I am not able to solve this problem. i have read the other errors but still i am not able to understand.

While i am doing .map or .subscribe to the service it gives me error like ***Property 'json' does not exist on type object.***

**This is my: continents.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { DataContinentsService } from '../../services/dataContinents.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';  
@Component({  
selector: 'app-continents',  
templateUrl: './continents.component.html',  
styleUrls: ['./continents.component.css'],  
providers: [DataContinentsService]  
})  
export class ContinentsComponent implements OnInit {  
continent: any;  
constructor(private dataContinentService: DataContinentsService) { }  
public getContinentInfo() {  
this.dataContinentService.getContinentDetail()  
.map((response) => response.json())  
.subscribe(res => this.continent = res.json()[0]);  
}  
ngOnInit() {}  
}
```

**This is my Service: DataContinentsService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';  
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';  
@Injectable()  
export class DataContinentsService {  
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}  
public getContinentDetail() {  
const _url = 'http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/india?fulltext=true';  
return this._http.get(_url);  
}  
}
```

**This is my Template: continents.component.html**

```
<h1>Continents</h1>  
<h3>Name: {{continent.name}}</h3>  
<h3>Capital: {{continent.capital}}</h3>  
<h3>Currency: {{continent.currencies[0].code}}</h3>  
<button (click)="getContinentInfo()">get details</button>
```

Comment: `.map((response) => response.json()) ` is not needed if you're using HttpClient, that's for the older `Http` class. In this case, `response` would be the parsed JSON already (which therefore doesnt have a `.json()` function)

Comment: OK. Thanks but its the same with .subscribe

Comment: You can try adding `getContinentDetail(): Observable<any>` to the service function definition. The `Observable<any>` bit will tell Typescript you're returning an Observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you've been reading some outdated documentation.
The old Http class used to return a response that did have a json() method.

The old Http class has been retired, and you are now properly using the HttpClient class. HttpClient's get() method returns an Observable of any  - it maps the response's json to an object for you. Typically, you'd specify the type of the object, like so:

```
   this.http.get<SomeObject>(url);
```

In lieu of that, you just get an Object.
In either case, there's no json() method on the returned object.

So, your service should do this:

```
public getContinentDetail(): Observable<Continent[]> {  
  const _url = 'http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/india?fulltext=true';  
  return this._http.get<Continent[]>(_url);  
}
```

you should subscribe something like this

```
this.dataContinentService.getContinentDetail().subscribe(continents: Continent[] => 
  this.continent = continents[0]);  
}
```

Comment: i am not able to understand... i am having error now in my service function. **Cannot find name Continent[]**

Comment: If you haven't, you'll need to define a Continent class that matches the properties in the json response

Comment: OK. sure thhanks