# Acces a complex json object in Ionic 3 and bind to view

Tags: android, html, json, typescript, ionic-framework

I making an Ionic 3 app. I have the following JSON object:

```
{
    "player": {
        "username": "thelegend",
        "platform": "xbox",     
       "stats": {
        "normal": {
            "shots": 5,
            "wins": 66             
        },
        "hard": {
            "shots": 5,
            "wins": 77               
        }           
    }
    }
}
```

I want to acces the following data from the JSON object:

```
stats: {normal:{ shots: "58", wins: "54"}, hard: {shots "34", wins: "43"}
```

This is my rest provider method in my Ionic 3 app:

```
 getStats(){ 
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

I call this method at a specific page:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getData();
}


  getData(){
   return this.results = this.rest.getStats();    
}
```

The api is working great and I can see the data in my Chrome developer tools. Now I want to bind this data on the view like this:

```
<ion-card>

    <ion-card-header>
      Wins
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>
      {{results}}
    </ion-card-content>

  </ion-card>
```

When I run the app it shows [object object]. I tried {{results.player.stats}} but it didn't work.

How can I bind the stats values on my view and access this?

Kind regards

Comment: Brace yourselves, angry "There is no such thing as a JSON object" comments incoming

Comment: Yeah, just display it in the view with the JSON pipe : `{{results | json}}`

Comment: Hi @jeremy, I am very new with JSON. I just followed the w3schools course and they called it JSON objects link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: Seems stats is available results.player.player.stats. First you can try alert this element and see if data is available then go for binding.

Comment: ...which won't prevent angry people from saying that JSON objects don't exist :)

Comment: I get an error when I use your solution @parwej it said cannot read property 'player' and your solution gives me a error: converting circular structure to JSON jeremy

Comment: @Fearcoder are you able to alert the data results.player.stats ?

Comment: getStats(){
   return this.results = this.rest.getStats(); 
   alert(this.results.player.player.stats);   
  } 

you mean like this?

Comment: @Fearcoder first of all in getData method no need to return. When setting the data in this.result try after the that statement like alert(JSON.stringify(this.result.player.stats))

Comment: Cannot read property player and no alert. When I change it to alert(JSON.stringify(this.results) I see [object object]

Comment: if you are using stringify then you should see the actual json data instead object object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api that I used is not working properly I changed to another api and everything was working fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert http response to json:

```
getStats(){ 
return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your time! I get an error on `.map` : map does not exist on type Observable<Object>

Comment: you need import map operator first... please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208801/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse)

Comment: I imported the operator I have problems now with `res.json())` I am looking on google to fix this. The error is Property json does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: can you post the api result you see from chrome?

Comment: I posted the results I want to acces this: `"stats": {
            "normal": {
                "shots": 5,
                "wins": 66             
            },
            "hard": {
                "shots": 5,
                "wins": 77               
            }           
        }` and bind it to the view

Comment: what http class you use? old Http or HttpClient? this case look similiar to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204981/angular2-json-does-not-exist-on-type-object)

Comment: I am using this one `import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';`